# Java + PDFBox on Linux

Tags: java, linux, pdfbox

I need to write a small program for a server which will use PDFBox. I'm writing under windows with NetBeans. How do I add PDFBox jar to my program jar once I export it to the server?

Answer (score 8):

You don't necessarily have to put `pdfbox.jar` into your application's jar. It's easier to keep them separate and just add them both to your classpath before running it.

For example, place both jars in the same directory and run:

```
$ java -cp myapp.jar:pdfbox.jar app.MainClass args
```

Comment: @gh0st Then now the idea is to upvote and accept this answer :-)